# Applicative <*> inside ReaderT StateT IO

Tags: haskell, monad-transformers

Inside a ReaderT StateT IO do block I am trying to call a function inside a Maybe with a Maybe parameter using `<*>` but that results in a type error.

`onMessage <*> (message update)`

If I wrap the expression using `return $ onMessage <*> (message update)` it type checks but then the function does not appear to be evaluated.

If I unwrap both the function and the argument and check for `Nothing` manually the function is called but that seems ugly.

Is there another operator to use in this context? These are my first Monad Transformer steps and the types are too perplexing to even try and hoogle an answer.

---

```
...

type Bot a = ReaderT (BotConfig a) (StateT (BotState a) IO)

...

processUpdate :: Update -> Bot a ()
processUpdate update = do
    BotConfig {tw_handlers = MessageHandlers {
          tw_onMessage = onMg
        }
    } <- ask

    onMg <*> (message update) -- this is what I would like to do
                              -- onMg :: Maybe (Message -> Bot a ())
                              -- message :: Update -> Maybe Message
```

Comment: Can you provide a small code snippet with the actual types? It's hard to understand as it is.

Comment: Hi Chi. Please see the code above.

Comment: Perhaps wrapping it with return is ok. The question then is how to force evaluation I tried seq, which didn't help and seqdeep which resulted in type errors again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you say, I understand that:

```
onMsg <*> (message update) :: Maybe ( Bot a () )
```

To execute the enclosed `Bot a ()` computation if it is a Just, you can use:

```
maybe (return ()) id $ onMsg <*> (message update)
```

**Update**

How does this "force" evaluation of the wrapped `Bot a ()` computation?

We know that `onMsg <*> ...` is either `Nothing` or `Just comp` where `comp` is a `Bot a ()` computation.

`comp` will be "evaluated" if it becomes part of the monadic sequence in the do-block.

The code above is the same as:

```
case (onMsg <*> ...) of
  Nothing    -> return ()
  Just comp  -> comp
```

So either `return ()` or `comp` will be the next step in the do-block.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. I am a bit confused though still. Looking at the `maybe` docs it says "The maybe function takes a default value, a function, and a Maybe value." So here `(return ())` is default, `id $ onMsg <*>` the partially applied function and `(message update)` the value? Are you using id to force evaluation?

Comment: Default value is `return ()` - a `Bot a` action; the function is `id`; the Maybe value is `onMsg <*> (message update)`.

Comment: As a minor alternative, `fromMaybe (return ()) $ onMg <*> (message update)`

Comment: @hcvst - updated answer to explain more how this "forces" evaluation.

Comment: Thank you very much @ErikR. Thanks also chi for your alt.